# Octave strings malipulating

Tags: string, count, octave

I have a problem in Octave
I want to find all different(!) pairs of two letters in a text(with no spaces, only letters)

For example:
my text = "abcdabcd"

i want find array(or vector?) that looks like: ab bc cd da

How do i do this in the easies way possible?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unique()` function to do this. The only trick is in creating the list of two characters which can be done by using two lines, shifted by one character.

```
str = "abcdabcd";
str(2,:) = shift (str, -1);
str(:,end) = [];  # remove last column
unique (str', "rows")
```

Comment: How do I access each pair?
If i write str(1) it doesn't give me first pair (ab) but the very first number (a).

I need that because now I want to count how many times each pair occurs in the text.

Comment: Of course not, what you have is a character matrix. `str(1)` only gets the first character, not the first row. Index it exacty as if it was a matrix or convert it to a cell array with `mat2cell()`. To get number of pairs, use `rows(str)`.

Comment: I have one more question. lets say I have this situation:

d=["aa";"bb";"cc";"dd"];

d=cellstr(d);

I want to do this:

x=cstrcat(d(1),"zz");

but that does not work because d(1) is not a string... My question is, how do I convert d(1)  (or whole d variable) into string variable?

Comment: you should open a new question for it. `d` is a cell array, if you use `()` to index it, you get another cell array, if you use `{}`, you get the elements inside the cells, a string in your case.

Comment: that worked! thanks
What is the opposit function of cellstr?

explanation: first I have: d=["aa";"bb";"cc";"dd"];

then I do: d=cellstr(d);

but then I want to have d back in shape like it was on the begining.